# why cant size of c++ arrays have a function call returning a constant

Tags: c++

I am not able to rationalize, as why cant we use size of an array as a function call returning a constant.
Following errror is encountered while compilation.
Error E2313 : Constant expression required in function main()

```
int getsize()
{
    return 2;
}

void main()
{
    const int x= getsize();
    int arr[x];

}
```

Comment: Note that "constant expression" has a specific meaning in the standard (which, for your code as written, `x` does not meet). It doesn't just mean any expression with `const`-qualified type.

Comment: "Constant expression" is a term which is constant *at compile time*, which is (theoretically) not the case in your example. It would work if you write: `const int x = 5; int arr[x];` because the compiler is sure the expression is constant.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't declare `getsize()` with the `constexpr` attribute. Many modern C++ compilers would be able to do what you want if you do use `constexpr`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options for this:

- `constexpr` in newest C++ compilers
- template class - based functions invoked like `getsize<>::value` - will work in almost all C++ compilers
- compile-time constants: `enum { size = ... }` - will work in probably all C++ and many C compilers
- `#define SIZE ...`, or `#define GETSIZE(args...) ...` - ugliest, but will work always

Answer (score 1):

The standard requires the array size to be a computable value at compile time, so that the compiler can determine the memory it has to allocate for your program on the stack.  In your case, even though you have the appearance of having declared a constant value, value `const int x` is only assigned at run-time, thus not helping in determining memory for the stack.

This is the reason, dynamically sized arrays are always allocated memory on the heap.

As pointed out earlier, some newer compilers (maybe g++) would allow you to be able to achieve what you asked, although that wouldn't be a good idea if you are aiming to have code that is portable across compilers.

If you instead defined x, you would not get Error E2313

```
#define arraySize 2

void main()
{
    int arr[arraySize];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you got the point array size should be `constant` but it also should be static at time of compilation. Your constant int return function cannot produce static constant value at compile time. If you use `constepxr` as suggested by Logicrat function will return a static constant value at compile time and it will compile by modern C++ compilers.